# Shadow Copies (VSS) and Non-Shared Folders

Tags: backup, ntfs

I'm trying to gain a better understanding of Shadow Copies through VSS.

According to these articles TechNet:

1. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636.aspx
2. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771305.aspx

The name of the service is "Shadow Copies of Shared Folders".

When configuring VSS (right click on drive --> Configure Shadow Copies ...) the dialog box contains the following text in the tab:

> Shadow copies allow users to view the contents of shared folders as the contents existed at previous points in time.  For information on Shadow Copies, click here.

The hyperlink opens a local help file that mirrors the TechNet articles.

Here's the kicker: ***Non-shared folders are also being copied.***

The D: drive of my server (Windows Server 2008 R2), has Shadow Copies enabled.  In the root of the drive, I have 6 folders.  Only one of them is shared, but ALL of them have "previous versions" available.

Is this expected behavior?  Or is there some other configuration which is causing non-shared folders to have Shadow Copies made?

Answer (score 0):

VSS operates at the volume level and synthesizes a new(old) volume based on copy-on-write pieces. This is at a wholly different level than shared folders which are materialized by the sharing services above the file system.